# broken pipe delimited file

Tags: parsing, powershell

I have a file with broken pipes as a delimiter (Hex A6?)

I am trying to read that file using powershell (import CSV)

```
Import-Csv .\a.dat -delimiter "¦"
```

However, nothing is being read. Any help appreciated to parse it.

sample data set:

```
F1 ¦ Part 1                ¦      51322 ¦   176           
F2 ¦ Part 2 ¦     473976 ¦   150           
F3 ¦ Part 3              ¦       7327 ¦    82
```

Comment: What encoding is your `a.dat` file in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround, i replaced the broken-pipe with a regular pipe. Now, i am able to read the file without issues.

```
 (Get-Content .\a.dat) -replace '¦', '|' | Out-File b.dat
```

Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your file encoding is off. Try using the `-Encoding UTF7` parameter. That seems to get the results you're after, in my testing.

```
Import-Csv -Path C:\test\a.dat -Delimiter ([char]166) -Encoding UTF7;
```

Comment: Did not work for me.....
`PS C:\Data> Import-Csv .\a.dat -delimiter ([char]166) -Encoding UTF7;
Import-Csv : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Encoding'.
At line:1 char:52
+ Import-Csv .\a.dat -delimiter ([char]166) -Encoding <<<<  UTF7;
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Import-Csv], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportCsvCommand`

Comment: What version of PowerShell are you running? I ran that on v4.0.

Comment: V2. How can I upgrade to V4?

Comment: Install the Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.1 and then install Windows Management Framework (WMF) Core 4.0. This is only for Windows 7, FYI. They must have added the `-Encoding` parameter to `Import-Csv` in PowerShell version 3.0 or 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

Import-CSV definitely doesn't like using that for a delimiter.
Here's a workaround (requires V3 but can be adapted to earlier versions):

```
$file = 'c:\testfiles\file.txt'
$char = [char]166
$Cols = 'Col1','Col2','Col3','Col4'

Get-Content $file |
Foreach {
 $ht=[ordered]@{}
 $parts = $_.split($char)
 0..($Cols.count -1) |
 foreach {$ht[$cols[$_]] = $Parts[$_].trim()}
 [PSCustomObject]$ht
 } | Format-Table -AutoSize



Col1 Col2   Col3   Col4
---- ----   ----   ----
F1   Part 1 51322  176 
F2   Part 2 473976 150 
F3   Part 3 7327   82
```